# Navigation Drawer Design android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I built a navigation drawer in my android app. There are white boundaries on both sides of screen which are coming above the drawer. I am not sure how to remove it.

[image]

Source Code for the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
        android:paddingRight="12dip" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:divider="#FFFFFF"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#E4E4E4" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:divider="#FFFFFF"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should try to remove the padding (left and right) of the `DrawerLayout` view.

Comment: remove paddings and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="12dip"
    android:paddingRight="12dip" >
```

to

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding from `content_frame1` :

```
android:paddingLeft="12dip"
        android:paddingRight="12dip"
```